# Where can I find a list of all of the QA sites, and the topics they cover?

Tags: support, area-51, stack-exchange

I am looking for the stuff above, so I can make non-duplicate proposals on area 51.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152376/where-to-get-description-of-se-webites/152382#152382

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [stackexchange.com/sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) lists all graduated sites and sites currently in public beta.
- [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) offers this break-down:

  - [Launched](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched)
  - [Currently in beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta)
  - [The rest](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress)

Answer (score 2):

You mean from StackExchange? https://stackexchange.com/sites