# Where to get description of SE webites?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

I see a lot of website down in the footer from the Stack Exchange group. Where can I get a brief description of each of them rather than going on each website and look what it talks about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see the [full list of Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list), which displays the short site description at a glance when in "list" view.

Answer (score 1):

You can also click on the "stack exchange" icon on the upper left corner and click on the down faced arrow. You would get a list of all the sites along with short descriptions in the "all sites" tab.